# How do I properly pass arguments more than once in a javascript object literal?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an object literal similar to this:

```
var test = {
    myFunc1: function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
            alert('myFunc1: ' + arguments[i]);
        }
    },
    myFunc2: function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
            alert('myFunc2: ' + arguments[i]);
        }
        this.myFunc1.apply(this.myFunc2, arguments);
    },
    myFunc3: function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
            alert('myFunc3: ' + arguments[i]);
        }
        this.myFunc2.apply(this.myFunc3, arguments);
    }
}
```

When I call "myFunc3"  I want it to call "MyFunc2" with all the arguments passed to "myFunc3".  This is working as expected.

When I call "myFunc3" I want it to call "myFunc2" with all passed arguments, and I want myFunc1 to be called with all passed arguments that were originally passed to "myFunc3".

```
test.myFunc3('a', 'b');
```

Currently when I call this, I get 4 alert boxes, 2 for myFunc3 and 2 for myFunc2. Then I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

If I need to pass a set of arguments more than one level deep in an object how can I do this?  Is there a better more correct way to do this?

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/taggedzi/fmPAQ/2/

Thanks in advance. Pure javascript only, no jquery please. Needs to work cross browser and platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `this` in `myFunc2` is not anymore `test` but `this.myFunc3`. This was provided by your `myFunc3` when calling `this.myFunc2.apply(this.myFunc3, arguments);`.

To visualize, your `myFunc2` is doing:

```
(this.myFunc3).myFunc1(...);

//instead of

(this).myFunc1(...);
```

You should pass in only `this` so you are using the same `this` for the other functions.

```
this.myFunc2.apply(this, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it works. You should use this instead of this.FuncX

```
var test = {
    myFunc1: function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
            alert('myFunc1: ' + arguments[i]);
        }
    },
    myFunc2: function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
            alert('myFunc2: ' + arguments[i]);
        }
        this.myFunc1.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    myFunc3: function () {
        for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
            alert('myFunc3: ' + arguments[i]);
        }
        this.myFunc2.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
test.myFunc3('a', 'b');
```

Comment: It was not me, but how does this differ from @JosephtheDreamer's answer?

Comment: I did not understand his explanation. I checked out myself. It is basically same what he is saying.

Comment: Yes, and code skeleton with explanation is better than the same code written fully with no explanation.